# Is the dominating set problem restricted to planar bipartite graphs of maximum degree 3 NP-complete?

Tags: computational-complexity, graph-theory

Does anyone know about an NP-completeness result for the DOMINATING SET problem in graphs, restricted to the class of planar bipartite graphs of maximum degree 3?

I know it is NP-complete for the class of planar graphs of maximum degree 3 (see the Garey and Johnson book), as well as for bipartite graphs of maximum degree 3 (see M. Chlebík and J. Chlebíková, "Approximation hardness of dominating set problems in bounded degree graphs"), but could not find the combination of the two in the literature.

Comment: The minimum edge dominating set is NP-hard in bipartite graphs of maximum degree 3, but I think this doesn't help with your problem.
Posting at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ might widen the pool of experts...

Comment: Ok thanks - I just heard about this website, I didn't know there are other similar ones ;)

Comment: And here is the link: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/is-the-dominating-set-problem-restricted-to-planar-bipartite-graphs-of-maximum-de

Comment: The problem remains NP-complete even for planar bipartite graphs of maximum degree 3.  See the nice reduction by @Jukka Suomela at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/is-the-dominating-set-problem-restricted-to-planar-bipartite-graphs-of-maximum-de/2508#2508 which works by introducing 3 new vertices in each edge.